# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XY-21' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am assigning next identity value to a variable and joining it to a string variable. but it is giving me error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XY-21' to data type int.

procedure is as follow:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPInsertNewDetail]
(
    @MLNo varchar(20)= null,
    @MCL varchar(20)= null,  --Suppose it has value XY-
    @MCCL VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT
)
AS
    DECLARE @Next_Id int 
    SELECT @Next_Id = IDENT_CURRENT('New_Master') + IDENT_INCR('New_Master') //Suppose it is 21
    PRINT @Next_Id
    SET @MCCL = @MCL + cast(@Next_Id as varchar)
    PRINT @MCCL
    INSERT INTO New_Master
    (MCCL, MLNo)
    VALUES (@MCCL, @MLNo)
    PRINT @MCCL
RETURN @MCCL
```

When I run procedure it return @MCCL as null but table has correct value.

Comment: Question says converting from  `VARCHAR` to `INT` but the code says convert from `INT` to `VARCHAR`. What is data type of `MCCL` column in `New_Master` table?

Comment: `@MCL` = NULL, do you set it anywhere? Or what value is given when the sproc is called?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky, it is varchar.

Comment: @NickyvV i am not setting null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from `RETURN @MCCL` line. `RETURN` statement in SQL is only used to return `INT` type. For output you don't need to include `RETURN`. If you remove that line your proc will work. I would also modify it to the following.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPInsertNewDetail]
    (
     @MLNo VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    ,@MCL VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    ,@MCCL VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Next_Id INT 
        SELECT @Next_Id = IDENT_CURRENT('New_Master') + IDENT_INCR('New_Master')
        PRINT @Next_Id
        SET @MCCL = @MCL + CAST(@Next_Id AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT @MCCL
        INSERT INTO New_Master
                ( MCCL, MLNo )
            VALUES ( @MCCL, @MLNo )
        PRINT @MCCL
    END
```

If you have specified `OUTPUT` on a parameter SQL server know that it has to return it once procedure finish executing. Here is simple test of `OUTPUT` variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].TEST_Out
    (
     @pSPIn VARCHAR(10)
    ,@pSPOut VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
     )
AS
    BEGIN 
        SET @pSPOut = @pSPIn + ' ' + 'this'
    END
```

---

```
DECLARE @stuff VARCHAR(20);

EXEC dbo.TEST_Out
    @pSPIn = 'blog'
    ,@pSPOut = @stuff OUTPUT

PRINT @stuff
```